# How to instruct dotnet test to skip certain non fixed unit test projects?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

Given:

- Large monolithic application
- Many unit test projects, some run slowly for one reason or another
- PR validation build is incremental, i.e. not all the projects are necessarily recompiled
- PR validation build runs `dotnet test --no-build`

Problem:

- `dotnet test --no-build` runs ALL the tests, even in those unit test projects which were not recompiled, because they are already up-to-date

I would like to improve the process by running only those unit test projects which satisfy either of these two conditions:

- The project was actually compiled (i.e. the C# code affecting the project has changed)
- The previous run has failed (i.e. some unit tests failed)

TBH, today I am running unit tests through ad-hoc powershell code, which:

1. Knows to identify the unit test assemblies
2. Runs unit tests using nunit3-console.exe
3. Touches a timestamp file upon successful completion
4. Checks the unit test assembly dll timestamp vs the aforementioned timestamp file to figure out if running unit tests is needed.

I do not like having this ad-hoc logic. I want to benefit from `dotnet test`, because it is standard and because of its ability to run code coverage without any external tools.

How can I preserve the desired behavior with `dotnet test --no-build` ?

P.S.

I cannot use `dotnet test` to also build the code because not all the projects are SDK style. We have Asp.Net and WCF applications too. The code targets full .NET Framework - net472.

Comment: I think it is not possible with straight dotnet test because it doesn't pertain state across test runs and honestly without explicit key (which you can request in microsoft ticket) it shouldn't do this. Your solution is good.

Comment: I am OK adopting part of my solution with `dotnet test`. But I want to use `dotnet test` for all the benefits of it.

Answer (score 1):

As this question has been dead for over 2 years and no one stepped up to answer it, here's my 0.02$.

Taken from the question:

> I would like to improve the process by running only those unit test projects which satisfy either of these two conditions:
>
> - The project was actually compiled (i.e. the C# code affecting the project has changed)
> - The previous run has failed (i.e. some unit tests failed)

As you mentioned you are working on a monolith broken down into many subprojects, if you really absolutely want to skip tests if subprojects haven't built then one option on your table is to:

- peel subprojects out of your monolith project and into their own repositories,
- move relevant unit tests into the subproject's repository,
- create CICD pipeline for each subproject that packages the subproject in a deployable unit (NuGet package?) and delivers it,
- update the monolith project to consume said packages,
- update the monolith's CICD pipeline to pull the latest dependencies from their repositories and run the pipeline.

Having said that, this shaves off some time from your build by adding a fair share of complexity.  Before going down that path, I recommend breaking down dependencies between subprojects and have all unit tests run in parallel in dedicated pipeline stages.

Hope this helps.